# GraphQL vs. REST for triggering Backend Action

Tags: api, rest, architecture, graphql

i am new to GraphQL, and i know that GraphQL has many advantages over REST specially when it comes to returning data from backend to client.

But my question is about the cases for triggering a **backend action**, when the returned **response data** from backend is not as important as **response code** for example, **since GraphQL always return 200.**, also in such cases we are not requesting dynamic data (ex: database entity data)

For example a case of developing an endpoint to /verifyEmail, /forgetPassword for example.

For such cases for example the client does not ask backend for data, but it is actually triggering an action, for example sending verifyEmail or forgetPassword email.

**my questions are:**

1. Is it favourable to use graphQl in those cases or REST? and why?
2. Also is it a good practice to develop an API which have both GraphQl and REST endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the needs of your application. If your backend needs to have a mixture of REST and GraphQL, because it's an older project or you are scaffolding something quickly, I think that's fine. There are plenty of reasons why you might keep your internal api on REST and serve your public data through GraphQL. That being said, you could definitely build your app to only consume GraphQL endpoints if you felt that was advantageous.

Since you are new to GraphQL I'd recommend checking out https://www.howtographql.com/ and doing a few tutorials before making a decision.